# Pivot table when same record appears multiple times

Tags: excel, duplicates, pivot-table, multi-select, countif

I have a data set where some fields have more than one value per record (i.e. a restaurant can have both dine-in and take-out dining options). As a result when I export data two lines are created per record. See example data below.

```
Org ID  Org Name          Dining Style  Restaurant Type
1001    Fast Burger       Dine-in       Fast Food
1002    Bob's Burgers     Dine-in       Fast Food
1002    Bob's Burgers     Take Out      Fast Food
1003    Main Street Diner Dine-in       Diner
1001    Fast Burger       Take Out      Fast Food
```

You'll see here that `Bob's Burgers` and `Fast Burger` appear twice since they each have `Dine-in` and a `Take Out` `Dining Style` options.

If I create a pivot table to count the number of restaurants by each dining style I'll get an accurate result since the `Dining Style` field is multi-select.

```
Row Labels  Count of Dining Style
Dine-in     3
Take Out    2
```

However, if I create pivot table to summarize the count by restaurant type I'll get an inaccurate result.

```
Row Labels  Count of Restaurant Type
Diner       1
Fast Food   4
Grand Total 5
```

This is an inaccurate count since the total number of `Fast Food` `Restaurant Type` should be 1 and the total number of `Diner` `Restaurant Type` should be 1.  I am getting an inaccurate result because for the `Restaurant Type` field a restaurant can only be characterized with one option but the restaurant appears multiple times in the data set since a restaurant can be characterized multiple ways for other fields.

Since the `Org ID` and `Org Name` are consistently applied across all records for the same establishment, how can I use that field within the pivot table (or some other Excel functionality) to accurately summarize the counts of the number of restaurant types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Excel 2013 or higher, when you create your pivot table, be sure to check the 'Add this data to the Data Model' checkbox. You will now see an option for Distinct Count in the Value Field Settings.